# gulp command line installation

Tags: gulp, workflow

I tried installing **gulp** via cmd on my mac but and used

```
nmp install gulp-cli --global
```

but couldn't install, instead it throws a `permission denied` error as show in the image below. Any suggestions?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dO91r.png

Comment: https://github.com/sindresorhus/guides/blob/master/npm-global-without-sudo.md

Answer (score 0):

It's all about permission problem. You can try,

`sudo npm install -g gulp-cli--global --allow-root`